# Should access to original concrete be considered when framing a basement?

Tags: concrete, basement, framing

I'm just wondering when I frame the basement is there a convenient way to allow access to the original concrete walls and floor. I've never noticed anybody ever having much concern for this, but basements settle and cracks can form. Wouldn't it be wise to allow some way to easily fix any problems that might arise in the future which is bound to happen eventually as the house ages? Is this not something I should be concerned with?

Comment: Your concerns are a good idea to check and prevent damage if there is a leak. However other than foundation drains I haven never seen much access.